# What is the first known Japanese loan word that entered the English language?

Tags: history, loanwords, japanese

I would like to ask here [a similar question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26259/12637) I have asked in the Spanish language stack. It is known that nowadays the English language has a lot a [words of Japanese origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Japanese_origin). But what was the first one to made its way into an English dictionary? What are the first English texts that use these words as part of the English language without having to explain them?

In Spanish we have both ***biombo*** (English: 'folding screen', imported from the Portuguese language, which imported it from Japanese *byóbu*, composed of *byó* 'protection' and *bu* 'wind') and ***catana*** (English: 'katana', from Japanese *katana*). Both are registered in texts from the 17th century and found in dictionaries from the 17th and early 18th centuries.

I have been trying to find some Japanese loan words in English texts using [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/), narrowing the search between the years 1500 and 1800, with no luck so far as everything I find are false positives. One candidate I've got is *typhoon* which I thought it came from Japanese 台風 *taifuu*, but the etymology dictionaries [say that it comes from Greek](https://www.etymonline.com/word/typhoon) *typhon* and was influenced by Chinese *taaifung*.

Finally it seems that I have found a good candidate: the word ***soy*** is considered to come from from Dutch *soya* and Japanese 醤油 *shōyu* and, [according to the Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soy), its first known use in English is from 1679. [Etymonline says](https://www.etymonline.com/word/soy):

> Etymology reflects Dutch presence in Japan before English and American merchants began to trade there.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Even if you can't access say OED, you can supply some candidates and perhaps even rule some out yourself. / I'm also not sure that this is going to be all that helpful to anyone trying to master English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth with all due respect, that depends on what you mean by "mastering English". Mastering a language may refer to speaking and writing it properly (something I have yet to learn), but it may also mean knowing about the etymology of words and their history and evolution, as well as about the history and evolution of the language itself. About your other concern, I apology and will try to find some words for myself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is very difficult to answer with references. Unless you have the entire text of an etymological dictionary where you can search by source language _and_ date; existing on-lie resources don't allow that. Also, what does 'mastery' have to do with anything? Are you accidentally thinking this is ELL?

Comment: @Mitch The whole point of ELU is to build up a repository of guidelines and where possible explanations concerning the correct use of English. While etymologies are obviously very important, including source languages, knowing which was the first Japanese loanword seems rather a piece of trivia. / OP has quickly responded with some research. Your comment 'This is very difficult to answer with references' surely mandates another close-vote reason, 'too broadly scoped' (though I've seen at least partial lists of loanwords by source language). Are you suggesting an answer without references?

Comment: In fact, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Japanese_origin) supplies a list of Japanese loanwords. I don't see that researching to find the one that appears to be the first accepted into the English lexicon is (a) a job that other contributors here should be expected to perform, or (b) going to give a result that many others will find of value.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1) ELU is not primarily about 'correct use' of English. 'Correct usage' is the primary domain of ELL. Many topics on ELU are difficult to answer by references. Yes, I am suggesting that an answer without references is appropriate under many circumstances. Some questions haven't been asked before; how can they possibly already have printed answers?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Re the wikipedia page of Japanese loanwords - a) I think you've misunderstood _something_ about how all this works. No one is _expected_ to do anything. If someone knows the answer, then great. b) This particular question is interesting not as pure trivia but about something it could say historically about cultural exchange.

Comment: You should put your 'soy' example as an answer (it's OK to self-answer)

Comment: @Mitch But ELU asks for supporting evidence, not circumstantial evidence (I looked at the dates of first use in English, and this was the earliest). / History and cultural exchange are fascinating and important. So are chemistry and biology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivia(l) and unlikely to help others.

Comment: @Mitch The _Nederlands Etymologisch Woordenboek_ (Dutch Etymology Dictionary) actually [suggests the opposite](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_X44k9-3j8C&pg=PA669&lpg=PA669&dq=soja+etymologie&source=bl&ots=ZRPZ3Fr9fn&sig=DiwUeBPcHb1I6C6Cz8N7P4njdOM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWmpuPoIvbAhXQ-qQKHcgGAIwQ6AEIXjAC#v=onepage&q=soja%20etymologie&f=false): that the dutch word come from Japanese. The book seems to be authoritative, written by a [Dutch linguist / etymologist specialised in Germanic linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_de_Vries_(linguist)).

Comment: @user That's crazy. This is exactly the kind of question thatELU was created for.

Comment: @JJJ I'm not sure why you're tagging me, because the OP found it. Also I don't understand what you mean by 'opposite'; the OP said it came from Dutch who got it from Japanese.

Comment: @Mitch I misread it, I thought he meant the Japanese got it from the Dutch and the English got it in turn from the Japanese (which would be weird seeing there was almost no soja in Western Europe at the time). I replied to you because you suggested adding it as an answer (and it would be a good one, seeing I misread ;) ).

Comment: Wouldn't "soy" only be a loan word if there were another prior word for 'soy' ?  It seems to me a loan word would be a word used for a concept or thing that already existed in the country or came to mean more than the purely Japanese meaning?  But if non soy bean soy was made I suppose that works

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=kimono kimono (n.)
1630s, from Japanese kimono, literally "a thing put on," from ki "wear, put on" + mono "thing."

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.857.903&rep=rep1&type=pdf  Japanese Loanwords Found
in the Oxford English Dictionary
and Kæmpfer’s the History of Japan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Japanese Contributions to the English Language: An Historical Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=GiCTPPnBuHEC&pg=PA27) (p27) has a list of words of Japanese origin that appeared in the 16th century:

- bonze
- buppo
- dairi
- Japan
- Kannon
- Kuge

(No Japanese words entered English before the 16th century.)

---

### More in depth:

First of all, it's important to realize that Japan's first contact with the west was with Portuguese missionaries in **1543**, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanban_trade).

The earliest document in English that I can find that talks about Japan is [The history of trauayle in the VVest and East Indies, and other countreys lying eyther way, towardes the fruitfull and ryche Moluccaes As Moscouia, Persia, Arabia, Syria, Ægypte, Ethiopia, Guinea, China in Cathayo, and Giapan](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A20049.0001.001/1:18.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) (letter written in 1565  and published in 1577). The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) has this as its earliest source for the word *Japan*, in fact. (The word *Japan* doesn't come directly from Japanese; it went from Japanese to Chinese to Malay before it ever reached English.) From what I read, this source mentions a lot of proper nouns taken from Japanese. Unfortunately for anyone living in this century, pretty much every single one of those words is an obsolete name or uses an obsolete spelling, so it'll take some effort to figure out what it's talking about. I already figured out some of the words:

- Giapan/Giapon/etc. = Japan
- Firando = [Hirado, Nagasaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirado,_Nagasaki)
- Meaco = [Kyoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyoto)
- Bungo = The historical [Bungo Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bungo_Province)
- Cangue = [Kuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuge) (its obsolete spelling is listed in the OED)
- Aquita = [Akita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_Prefecture), probably
- Amida = [Amitābha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amit%C4%81bha), which I think ultimately comes from Sanskrit, not Japanese at all
- Xaca = [Shaka](http://www.taleofgenji.org/shakyamuni.html) = Buddha
- Bonzii/Bonziae = bonze

  - The important thing to realize with this is that the former comes directly from Japanese (I'm pretty sure) while the latter's etymology isn't directly from Japanese. The OED's entry for *bonze*, whose earliest attestation is from 1588, has this for etymology:

    > probably < French *bonze*, < Portuguese *bonzo* (early modern Latin *bonzus, bonzius*); according to Col. Yule probably < Japanese *bonzô* or *bonzi*, < Chinese *fan seng* ‘religious person’, or of Japanese *bo-zi*, < Chinese *fă-sze* ‘teacher of the law’. Some of the earlier English forms appear to represent the Japanese word directly.